# Cubes in Powerbuilder

Tags: sql-server-2008, olap, powerbuilder, cube, olap-cube

I am working as Powerbuilder/SQL Server Junior Programmer, and I need to use OLAP cubes in my Powerbuilder app, but I do not know how to link them.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: No one knows how to deal with cubes in Powerbuilder?